# Retrieve the nextval from a sequence using activerecord in Ruby on Rails 3.2.14 / Ruby 2.0.0 / PostgreSQL 9.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, postgresql-9.2, rails-postgresql

This should be SO simple.  I want to retrieve the nextval of a sequence... it's not a default value... it's not a primary key... it's not a foreign key.  In rare cases, I need a sequence number for a user supplied value.

I've tried the following:

```
@nextid = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT nextval('xscrpt_id_seq')")
```

and what I get back is:

```
#<PG::Result:0x007fe668a854e8 @connection=#<PG::Connection:0x00000003aeff30>>
```

And by using

```
@nextid[0]["nextval"]
```

I can get the correct value, but it doesn't seem like the right way to approach the problem.  I've searched, I read "Pro Active Record", which said to use:

```
M_script.find_by_sql("SELECT nextval('xscript_id_seq')")
```

but, that didn't work.

Any hints on the "correct" (Rails way) to retrieve a nextval from a sequence in ROR, would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I believe:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( "SELECT nextval('xscrpt_id_seq')" )
```

is the correct solution.  As I said in my original question, I checked the book "Pro Active Record" and it is their recommended solution.  I'm still not exactly sure how *ActiveRecord* is making the connection, or if there's any maintenance I need to do (such as closing it).

*ActiveRecord* used to have a `next_sequence_number` method, but that has been deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to use `select_value` and `sequence_name`:

```
Xscrpt.connection.select_value("select nextval('#{Xscrpt.sequence_name}')").to_i
```

Comment: select_value function is super helpful and no need to fetch like [0]['nextval']. Thanks @kbrock

Comment: You don't need the #to_i at the end, #select_value casts the value to Integer for you.

Answer (score 1):

This works too:

```
 @seq = Smodelname.find_by_sql(" select seq_name.nextval as id from dual ")[0][:id]
```

Answer (score 1):

At least with Rails 5.1.7, be careful:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value
```

increments the sequence within a transaction only for the first call. When you execute it multiple times, you'll get always the same value and the sequence is not incremented.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute
```

does not cache and works as expected