# How to make activerecord-import to use an sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord-import

I have the following model:

```
                                                  Table "public.models"
        Column        |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                   
----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 id                   | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('models_id_seq'::regclass)
 research_provider_id | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 covered_company_id   | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 publication_date     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 created_at           | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at           | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 insights_id          | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('models_insights_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "models_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_22d32db7ac" FOREIGN KEY (covered_company_id) REFERENCES companies(id)
    "fk_rails_3a764bb9c1" FOREIGN KEY (research_provider_id) REFERENCES companies(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "model_product_groups" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_1866a14ba0" FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES models(id)
    TABLE "model_analysts" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_c7730c705b" FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES models(id)
```

And I'm creating the objects using ActiveRecord, with:

```
   Model.new(
        # insights_id: 
        research_provider_id: company.id,
        covered_company_id: covered_company_id,
        publication_date:  Time.current - rand(1..20).day,
    ......
   )
```

What value should I pass to `insights_id` to use the `models_insights_id_seq` sequece? Tried `DEFAULT` and not passing anything and both fail to use the sequence, ie, making activerecord-import to generate `nextval('public.models_insights_id_seq')`

Note: This question is about to instruct `activerecord-import` to generate `nextval('public.models_insights_id_seq')` for the `insights_id` column, and not about using ActiveRecord to get the sequence next value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the nextval from a sequence using activerecord in Ruby on Rails 3.2.14 / Ruby 2.0.0 / PostgreSQL 9.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954524/retrieve-the-nextval-from-a-sequence-using-activerecord-in-ruby-on-rails-3-2-14)

Comment: @AlexeySuslyakov different scenarios, activerecord-import is used to populate large set of data, also this is not about gettting a sequence value, but instruct activerecord-import to generate the right SQL.

Comment: oh, got it. Sorry then

Answer (score 1):

Faced with same issue today. Just used another way for records import. Instead of importing of collection of AR objects, build a collection of attributes hashes without sequence parameters and then import them through `Model.import`. This way works for me.

Example. Given I have position column with default sequence value: 
`position | integer | not null default nextval('file_exports.task_file_item_position_seq'::regclass)`

In this code next sequence value will be set by Postgres automatically in 
each `FileExports::TaskFileItem` record.

```
... 
params = file_records.map do |file_record|
  build_file_item_params(file_record) 
end 

def build_file_item_params(file_record) 
  { 
    name: "some_name", 
    link: file_record.file.url 
  } 
end 

FileExports::TaskFileItem.import!(params, validate: true)
```

Comment: Hi Marsmust. Can you provide some example code for your new solution?

Comment: sure, given I have position field with default sequence value:
`
 position          | integer                     |  not null default nextval('file_exports.task_file_item_position_seq'::regclass)
`
```
    ...
  params = file_records.map do |file_record|
    build_file_item_params(file_record)
  end

  FileExports::TaskFileItem.import!(params, validate: true)

  def build_file_item_params(file_record)
    {
      name: "some_name",
      link: file_record.file.url
    }
  end

```

(SORRY, can't add formatting to the comment)

Comment: That marsmust. Could you edit your answer to include this? There you will able to format it.